# What is posix.waitpid in cProfile output?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, cprofile

Have a flask application and when I profile it, I get `posix.waitpid` as the most time-consuming process. Not sure where this is being called from. How can I improve on this one?
[image: cProfile output]

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500943/how-to-improve-the-code-performance-if-the-most-time-consuming-part-comes-to-pos), maybe?